# Small Java exception that I can't understand

Tags: java, exception, jmonkeyengine

Can you help me resolve this?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jme3.asset.AssetNotFoundException: Interface/splash.png
    at com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem.showSettingsDialog(JmeDesktopSystem.java:112)
    at com.jme3.system.JmeSystem.showSettingsDialog(JmeSystem.java:128)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.start(SimpleApplication.java:125)
    at adventure.Q3World.main(Q3World.java:85)
```

It used to work, then I had to repackage everything and now I might've forgotten a setting or likewise in Eclipse. The splash file is there but it is not on some path.

What I'm trying to to is this, which works in my previous build:

`settings.setSettingsDialogImage("Interface/splash.png");`

I've also tried adding the path to the resource panel but to no other effect:

[image]

And in Java build path, the resource is listed but it's still not working:

[image]

The larger code block that I want to work and that which is working in the built jar but not from within eclipse juno is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("quake3level.zip");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            useHttp = true;
        }
        Q3World app = new Q3World();
        AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
        settings.setTitle("Dungeon World");
        settings.setSettingsDialogImage("Interface/splash.png");
        app.setSettings(settings);

        app.start();
    }
```

### Success

[image]

Comment: http://jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/running-helloterrain/ might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell us how you run your code (e.g. command line, if so, what is the classpath), and where all the locations of splash.png are in your folder structure?

The file needs to be on the classpath, as that appears to be from where this code loads the image.

http://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/source/browse/trunk/engine/src/desktop/com/jme3/system/JmeDesktopSystem.java?spec=svn10038&r=10038#112

```
    String iconPath = sourceSettings.getSettingsDialogImage();        
    if(iconPath == null){
        iconPath = "";
    }
    final URL iconUrl = JmeSystem.class.getResource(iconPath.startsWith("/") ? iconPath : "/" + iconPath);
    if (iconUrl == null) {
        // *****LINE 112 below*****
        throw new AssetNotFoundException(sourceSettings.getSettingsDialogImage());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I try run the code from Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Do you have source folders setup for your resources as well as for your Java code?

Comment: I updated the question with more info how it looks. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Look in java build path. The folder (or jar) that contains the `Interface/splash.png` resource should be listed.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I've been there and done that. I updated the question to display how it looks. I hope we can see what is causing the exception.

Comment: The "Source Folder Selection" window is actually in the way of what I'd like to see :) I just want to see what source folders and jars are listed in your build path. The "Order and Export" tab usually summarises this.

Comment: Success! Now it's working! You're right: I had made an exlusion instead of an inclusion, fixed it and now it works. Your answer helped me fixed this. Thanks a lot.